# Why can't I execute system("xxx.Py -yyy -zzz...") on Ruby?

Tags: python, ruby

My OS is Win7

I have a python file(xxx.py), and I need execute it on ruby

my ruby code:

```
system("xxx.py -yyy -zzz");
```

and run it no result, but it can run on `cmd(xxx.py -yyy -zzz)`

and ruby can run `system("java -h")`; or `system("python -h")`; success.

What's problem with me???

Comment: Try `system("python xxx.py -yyy -zzz")`?

Comment: OH MY GOD~~ it can run!!! Thank YOU :)

Comment: @Dogbert I filled out your answer in full below credit goes to you.

Comment: Note that a semicolon at the end of a line is optional in ruby, and most people depreciate using it unless it's in the middle of a line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to fill out Dogberts answer in full

Using `system("python xxx.py -yyy -zzz")` should prrovide you with what you want. This is because your python script is probably not +777 or is missing its shebang line.